# Как получить строковое представление числа?

Tags: c++

У меня есть переменная `string file` и есть переменная `int num`

Мне надо сделать так `file = num;`

Но `num` вместо значения `num = "0";` имеет такое `num = 0;`
Мне надо что бы `num = 0;` изменился в `num = "0";`

Дальше мне нужно делать так `num++;`

`0` - это файл без расширения.

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы его можно было понять с первого раза. Например, что-то вроде "как получить строковое представление числа".

Comment: `auto file = std::to_string(num)`

Comment: Еще интересует как просто `num` изменить в файл, что бы не передавать данные в `file`

Comment: @int3 можно как то сделать без добавления #include <string>

Comment: @int3, а зачем auto?  Лучше показать, что это  string

Comment: В принципе вопрос решено мне подходит `to_string(num)` но если можно это сделать без подключения библиотеки `#include <string>` в С++17 пишите свои идеи.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan мне кажется очевидным, что возвращаемое значение `std::to_string` - это `std::string`. Вопрос вкуса и стиля.

Comment: Вообще, посмотрите на [sprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) (можно будет сразу в одном вызове формировать имя из разных компонент)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я приведу 3 варианта решения из многочисленных возможных, чтобы больше не было такого вопроса....

```
int num;
std::cin >> num;
std::string file;
// первый вариант
file =  std::to_string(num)
//второй вариат    
while (num) {
    file.insert(file.begin(), num % 10 + '0');
    num /= 10;
}    
//третий вариант    
std::ostringstream os;
os << num;
file = os.str();
```

P.S. можно и без подключения библиотек, тогда  ваш `file` должен быть С_строкой, если  хотите сохранять, а не просто передать в поток. Это немного усложнит код:

```
int t = num;
size_t i = 0;
while (t) {
    t /= 10;
    ++i;
}   
char* file = new char[i + 1];
file[i] = '\0';
while (num) {
    file[--i] = char(num % 10) + '0';
    num /= 10;
}   
// использование file;
delete  []file;
```

Comment: Сколько же цифр вы ожидаете в `int`, что решили использовать `new`/`delete`?

Comment: @avp,  Да, можно также  брать  массив размера  больше десяти, но я захотел явно показать количество элементов массива